# Laravel: Best way to intercept withError call

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently using Laravel and I'd like to be able to extend the withError call to log it everytime it's called. I know it goes through the RedirectResponse object in this call:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (starts_with($method, 'with'))
    {
        return $this->with(snake_case(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
    }

    throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on Redirect.");
}
```

however this is part of the Illuminate (Laravel) vendor code and I Don't want to modify it in case I Want to update Laravel later. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

References:

- http://laravel.com/docs/errors
- http://fideloper.com/laravel4-error-handling

Comment: Maybe you should only rtype hint for `BadMethodCallException`. The OP said nothing about logging other errors.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood, I'm trying to override a method in RedirectResponse.php not error handling.